# Explaining how to take derivatives in this form: $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}x^{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2)!}}$

Tags: derivatives, self-learning

I was going through some calculus integration and had the idea of implementing derivates while in this form: $\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}x^{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2)!}}$

It surprisingly seems to work:

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import *
x = symbols('x')
def derivative(n):
    derive = (factorial(n)/factorial(n-1))*x**(factorial(n-1)/factorial(n-2))
    return derive
```

```
derivative(3)
```

$=3x^2$

Although I wished to know as to whether there was a stronger understanding beyond this approach, and perhaps it's used elsewhere or has a specific name for it which I have not come across? Furthermore, what's the theoretical understanding for this approach working?

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Do you want to know how to find the derivative of that expression using math?

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Perhaps I was looking for a philosophical perspective but missed the idea of posting questions relevant to the maths section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply have that by definition

> $$n!=n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdots \cdot 2\cdot 1$$

therefore

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} =n$$

$${\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2)!}} =n-1$$

and then

$$\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}x^{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2)!}} =nx^{n-1}$$

Comment: I see! pardon my philosophical language. It seems as if the RHS is the general and the LHS are the particulars, hence we cannot deny the concept of differentiation of any of its parts otherwise it leads to a contradiction?

Comment: @Stackcans Those are two completely equivalent form to write the same expression. $n$ and $n!/(n-1)!$ represent the same number.